# How can I prove this formula for Hopfield model?

Tags: proof-writing, neural-networks, statistical-mechanics

Studying fluctuations theory in Hopfield model I found this formula for the derivative of an observable:

$\frac{d\left<O \right>}{ds} = \beta\sqrt{\alpha} \sum_{ab} \left < O \xi_{a, b} \eta_{a, b} \right>_s - s \sum_{a} \left< O \xi_{a, s+1 } \eta_{a, s+1} \right>_s + \frac{s(s+1)}{2} \left < O \xi_{s+1,s+2} \eta_{s+1,s+2}\right>_s \\$

I can't find any reference for the proof of this formula. Everywhere there's written that are just long and boring calculations. Can anyone give me a reference where I can find the full derivation of the formula.
Thanks!

Comment: How is the observable defined?

Comment: $O$ is a smooth function of the overlap $(q_1,...q_s)$ and $(p_1,...,p_s)$ and $\xi_{ab} \equiv \sqrt{N} ( q_{ab} - \bar{q})$ and $\eta \equiv \sqrt{N} ( p_{ab} - \bar{p})$ are the rescaled overlap. 
Here is a reference https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3096v1